# How can one use wpa_cli to connect to a WPA network without a password?

Tags: wireless, networking

The guest network does not have a password.  Yet, if I run wpa_passphrase to get a key I neet to provide a 8+ character passphrase.

```
> scan
OK
> scan_results
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
80:ea:96:ef:4d:9c   2437    -49 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    Sook Wah's Wi-Fi Network
6c:f3:7f:57:69:61   2437    -51 [ESS]   UCSFguest
d8:c7:c8:e9:80:63   2412    -46 [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    eduroam
d8:c7:c8:e9:80:61   2412    -47 [ESS]   UCSFguest
6c:f3:7f:57:69:62   2437    -52 [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    p@8n@55u5mu
d8:c7:c8:e9:80:60   2412    -47 [WPA-EAP-TKIP][WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]  UCSFwpa
6c:f3:7f:57:69:63   2437    -52 [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    eduroam
d8:c7:c8:ea:40:62   2412    -46 [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    p@8n@55u5mu
d8:c7:c8:ea:40:63   2412    -47 [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    eduroam
d8:c7:c8:ea:40:60   2412    -49 [WPA-EAP-TKIP][WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]  UCSFwpa
74:ea:3a:a7:5d:76   2427    -70 [WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][ESS]    LR0e
d8:c7:c8:e9:80:62   2412    -47 [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    p@8n@55u5mu
d8:c7:c8:ea:40:61   2412    -47 [ESS]   UCSFguest
6c:f3:7f:57:69:60   2437    -52 [WPA-EAP-TKIP][WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]  UCSFwpa
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
```

I am following these guidelines:  http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/27/how-to-use-wpa_cli-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network/

Comment: Short of a WPA2-Enterprise connection which is governed by cert auth and such, there is no such "No Password WPA" network, as evidenced in the scan output.  Is the Guest network open but with a Captive Portal that makes you accept something?  If so, then I believe your issue isn't going to be resolved in the command line `wpa_cli` as that operates differently than actual WPA auth.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: **set_network 0 key_mgmt NONE**

Here is an example to connect to a network with security turned off:

```
> scan
OK
CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
> scan_results 
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
f8:d1:11:23:c2:2f       2412    76      [ESS]   BAYINET
f8:d1:11:23:c1:e9       2412    47      [ESS]   BAYINET
> add_network
0
> set_network 0 ssid "BAYINET"
OK
> set_network 0 key_mgmt NONE
OK
> enable_network 0
OK
CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
Trying to associate with f8:d1:11:23:c2:2f (SSID='BAYINET' freq=2412 MHz)
Association request to the driver failed
Associated with f8:d1:11:23:c2:2f
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to f8:d1:11:23:c2:2f completed (auth) [id=1 id_str=]
> quit
```

you need the **set_network 0 key_mgmt NONE** part after you added your network SSID/BSSID then just enable the network with "enable network " and the interface is connecting...

Answer (score 1):

Well, from looking at the output you posted, and the article you are following, you do not need to enter the second part, the

```
set_network 0 psk "SupahSecretPassphrase"
```

All you have to do is enter the first command, and looking at the output of your scan it should be

```
set_network 0 ssid UCSFguest
```

and you should be able to connect. I am saying based on the article you followed, and the output you posted in your question, if look at the list, the SSID you're trying to connect to, (I assume as it is the only open network, or guest network)

> d8:c7:c8:ea:40:61   2412    -47 [ESS]   UCSFguest

Does not show **any** security info like the others, for example

> 6c:f3:7f:57:69:60   2437    -52 [WPA-EAP-TKIP][WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]  UCSFwpa

Shows it to be a protected network using WPA, which you tell by the

> [WPA-EAP-TKIP][WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]

Try just using the connect command, and it should work.